# Sometimes appcelerator start a 5 minute loading and after give this error

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

After i tried to share a project with git, my appcelerator sometimes give me this error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Please send the output you see in the console window and also what you have inside "Details"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by removing the share option on a project.

Comment: can you elaborate? so other who are facing the same problems in the future might find this solution...

Comment: sure. i Started to have this issue when i started using git for a my project. I did right clic on that project, team > share > disconnect and with this i disabled git on it. Without git all work fine.

Comment: That's interesting @Steph8. Would it be possible to report this as a bug at [Appcelerator's JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org) with a reproducible test case and steps/environment?

Comment: At the moment no because i fix the issue with a clear installation of all git component. Probably i corrupted the installation the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your Titanium studio is not completely updated. After setting Android SDK go to help menu
then select

1.Check updates

download and install all updates listed

After successful updates again Goto Help menu, then select

2.check for Titanium updates

install all updates and restart Titanium studio.

Restart the studio. And check if the problem occur again. Thanks.